# Rounding off floating point numbers while building a map

Tags: groovy

I'm looping through an XMP response like so:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <SearchRS>
     <SearchStatus>SUCCESS</SearchStatus>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>111.11</Ticket>
         <Taxes>1.11</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Bob</Name>
         <Ticket>222.22</Ticket>
         <Taxes>2.22</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>333.33</Ticket>
         <Taxes>3.33</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Bob</Name>
         <Ticket>444.44</Ticket>
         <Taxes>4.44</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>0.0</Ticket>
         <Taxes>0.0</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
 </SearchRS>
```

So I'mm creating a map that gather this info with the average ticket+taxes for each name. Here's the code:

```
 def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
 def map = [:]
 xml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'Name'}.unique().each { name -> 
    map[name] = xml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'Itinerary' && name == it.Name.text() }.collect { Double.parseDouble(it.Ticket.text()) + Double.parseDouble(it.Taxes.text())}.findAll {it}.with { sum() / size() }
}
```

This gives me a result that looks like this:

```
 [Joe:10.9101234, Bob:20.319999999999997]
```

I'd like to round it off to look like this but I don't know where to place the round(2) method. call:

```
 [Joe:10.91, Bob:20.31]
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simplifying your example. Instead of nesting iterations you could use Groovy's `inject {}` operation that is something similar to popular fold-left operation - it iterates over the list and accumulates the result to a different form. Take a look at this example:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

import java.math.RoundingMode

def input = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <SearchRS>
     <SearchStatus>SUCCESS</SearchStatus>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>111.11</Ticket>
         <Taxes>1.11</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Bob</Name>
         <Ticket>222.22</Ticket>
         <Taxes>2.22</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>333.33</Ticket>
         <Taxes>3.33</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Bob</Name>
         <Ticket>444.44</Ticket>
         <Taxes>4.44</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>0.0</Ticket>
         <Taxes>0.0</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
 </SearchRS>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

def result = xml.'*'.findAll { node ->
    node.name() == 'Itinerary'

  }.inject([:]) { Map<String, List<BigDecimal>> map, NodeChild node ->
    // sum ticket + tax
    def value = node.Ticket.text().toBigDecimal() + node.Taxes.text().toBigDecimal()
    // collect all values as Name => List of prices
    map.merge(node.Name.text(), [value], { a, b -> a + b })

    return map

  }.collectEntries { String k, List<BigDecimal> v ->
    // calculate average price per name and round the final result
    [(k): (v.sum() / v.size()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)]
  }

println result
```

At first we filter all child nodes to work only with the `Itinerary` nodes. Next we call `inject([:])` which starts with an empty map and we start iterating over all nodes. Each step of iteration does:

- calculate the value by adding `Ticket` and `Taxes` values and stores it as `BigDecimal`
- it calls [`Map.merge(key, value, remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), so if the given key does not exist it puts the key with the value stored in the list. If it exists, we adds the value to the existing list (by merging the new value packed in the list)
- it returns the map so in the next iteration modified map is used as `map` variable

At the very end we call `collectEntries` method that remaps initial map - it converts `Map<String, List<BigDecimal>>` to `Map<String, BigDecimal>`, where value stored as a `BigDecimal` is an average calculated from the values stored in the list. When we calculate final value we can call `BigDecimal.setScale(scale, mode)` to round it.

When you run this example you will get something like this:

```
[Joe:149.63, Bob:336.66]
```

#### For Java 7

Java 8 introduced this `Map.merge(key, value, remappingFunction)` useful method. However it can be expressed in more imperative way like:

```
def key = node.Name.text()
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
  map.put(key, [])
}
map.put(key, map.get(key) << value)
```

If you use Java older than Java 8, use these 4 lines instead of `map.merge(...)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is NodeChild defined as?

Comment: The .merge is causing an error. "No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.merge() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList, comparomatic.ApiService$_getReply_closure2_closure16) values: [Joe, [21.16], comparomatic.ApiService$_getReply_closure2_closure16@2e139060] Possible solutions: grep(), keySet(), size(), clone(), keySet(), size()

Comment: What Java version you use? Merge was added in Java 8 API. This method is just a simplification of "if map does not contain a key, add a key, and then update it".

Comment: I finally got back to this code and was able to get this to work perfectly. Using 1.7.079. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a slight simplification of Szymon's answer, we can use the `toBigDecimal` method of the `node` (NodeChild instance) directly and we can replace the merge with a `withDefault` call to the initial map:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

import java.math.RoundingMode

def input = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <SearchRS>
     <SearchStatus>SUCCESS</SearchStatus>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>111.11</Ticket>
         <Taxes>1.11</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Bob</Name>
         <Ticket>222.22</Ticket>
         <Taxes>2.22</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>333.33</Ticket>
         <Taxes>3.33</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Bob</Name>
         <Ticket>444.44</Ticket>
         <Taxes>4.44</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
     <Itinerary>
         <Name>Joe</Name>
         <Ticket>0.0</Ticket>
         <Taxes>0.0</Taxes>
     </Itinerary>
 </SearchRS>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

def result = xml.Itinerary.inject([:].withDefault{[]}) { m, n ->
  m[n.Name] << n.Ticket.toBigDecimal() + n.Taxes.toBigDecimal()
  m
}.collectEntries { name, v ->
  [(name): (v.sum() / v.size()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)]
}

println result
```

or arguably even simpler with groupBy on the name first:

```
result = xml.Itinerary.groupBy { it.Name }.collectEntries { k, v -> 
  def c = v.collect { it.Ticket.toBigDecimal() + it.Taxes.toBigDecimal() }
  [k, (c.sum() / c.size).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)]
}
```

prints:

```
~> groovy test.groovy 
[Joe:149.63, Bob:336.66]
```

assuming I've understood the problem correctly.